# How to open application using URL?

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

I have implemented all the required things but had no success. I want to open the application from browser - but not with just **URL schema** like a "callback".

I have something like "http://11.11.21.114:8081/signup/callback?signupCode=123?id=20" so how can I identify this url to open my application?

Comment: this url local host api?

Comment: this is just dummy URL, But I need to open my app when ever call this URL

Comment: You can open your app using urlSchemes.

Comment: You need to use Deep link for it

Comment: https://kitefaster.com/2016/07/13/how-to-open-ios-app-with-custom-url/     This should help.

Answer (score 9):

**Use Universal Links**

**But it will only work with Public website URL, that should be accessible to Apple Servers.**

The only thing you need is to have https server and access to upload a associated domains file.

> When you support universal links, iOS 9 users can tap a link to your
>   website and get seamlessly redirected to your installed app without
>   going through Safari. If your app isn’t installed, tapping a link to
>   your website opens your website in Safari.

Apple Link : => [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Follow this nice tutorial : =>  [Universal Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection?utm_source=raywenderlich.com%20Weekly&utm_campaign=95f29cf4fc-raywenderlich_com_Weekly5_31_2016&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_83b6edc87f-95f29cf4fc-415182745)

Answer (score 2):

Add Innformation In Info.Plist File

[image: In Url Identifier Enter Your Package Name && Url schemes add Application Name]

1. In Url Identifier Enter Your Package Name && Url schemes add
   Application Name
2. open link like `schemesname://` Then Open Your App

Comment: Can you provide example with dummy app name. so it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score -4):

To Launch application from Url , **Deep Link** is used . Here is tutorial for complete step by step for opening application :

http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Once its done , just add url into **Xcode Plist file** , then passing url on browser will launch iOS Application.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: This is not support to entire URL