# Link to open the application via email

Tags: swift, hyperlink, info-plist

I'm doing an application in swift and I need to generate a URL of the application itself, and this url has to be sent by email so the user clicks and opens the application.

I configured the same in INFO P-LIST as for example:
testExample: //
But I only get digitala in the browser to open my app, how do I get to send this address as a link for the user to click and open the application?

Can someone help me please, I'm days away from this.

[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287958/how-to-open-application-using-url) what are you looking for?

Comment: Are looking for deep linking, Right ??

Comment: This link will help you : http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: Yes, but I still can not do it, I can not concatenate the link in my application with another link for the user to click and open the app

Comment: Can you show me what did you put in the URL Schemes?

Comment: I edited the post with the information.